# while loop wont work inside of the other while loop

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm scripting in roblox lua and when I try to put a while loop in the first it messes up the first sequence of code can someone give me hand in fixing this?

The problem is that when the humanoid makes it to tar2 he stops there and wont move I want him to continue running to the points but while also having it so where if a actual person comes by then he runs after him instead.

```
local larm = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Left Arm")
local rarm = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Right Arm")
local plr = game.Players:GetChildren()
local tar1 = game.Workspace.tar1
local tar2 = game.Workspace.tar2
local tar3 = game.Workspace.tar3
local tar4 = game.Workspace.tar4
local pos = {tar1, tar2, tar3, tar4}
local char = script.Parent
local Hum = char.Humanoid
torso = char.Torso
GoTo = 0 

while true do
    wait(1) 
    if GoTo == 0 then   
          Hum:MoveTo(pos[1].Position)
    end

    if (torso.Position - pos[1].Position).magnitude < 5 then 
            GoTo = 1 
    end

    if GoTo == 1 then 
            Hum:MoveTo(pos[2].Position)
    end

    if (torso.Position - pos[2].Position).magnitude < 5 then 
        GoTo = 2
    end

    if GoTo == 2 then 
        Hum:MoveTo(pos[3].Position)
        Goto = 3
    end

    if (torso.Position - pos[3].Position).magnitude < 5 then 
        GoTo = 4
    end

    if GoTo == 5 then 
        Hum:MoveTo(pos[4].Position)
    end


    while true do 
        wait(0.1)
        plrs = game.Players:GetChildren()
        for i,plr in ipairs(plrs) do 
            if plr.Character ~= nil then 
            tor = plr.Character.Torso
                if (torso.Position-tor.Position).magnitude <= 5 then 
                        GoTo = 0                
                        Hum:MoveTo(tor.Position)
                end 
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: When does the inner loop ever exit?

Comment: I guess it never does.

Comment: I don't understand the logic in your code so I can't comment beyond that but perhaps you should look over your code again and try to work out what your logic is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines! [Coroutines](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Coroutine) are the bombdiggety. They let you do multiple while loops at once in a single script.

```
local larm = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Left Arm")
local rarm = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Right Arm")
local plr = game.Players:GetChildren()
local tar1 = game.Workspace.tar1
local tar2 = game.Workspace.tar2
local tar3 = game.Workspace.tar3
local tar4 = game.Workspace.tar4
local pos = {tar1, tar2, tar3, tar4}
local char = script.Parent
local Hum = char.Humanoid
torso = char.Torso
GoTo = 1

function normalCor() -- run around
while true do
    wait(1)
    for i=1, 4 do
        if GoTo == i then
        Hum:MoveTo(pos[i].Position)
        end
        if (torso.Position - pos[i].Position).magnitude < 5 then
            GoTo = GoTo + 1
            if GoTo == 5 then
                GoTo = 1
            end
            --[[
            The above _can_ be done in a single statement:
            "GoTo = (GoTo+1)%4+1"
            "a % 4" gets the remainder of a / 4 ]]
        end
    end
end
end
cr = coroutine.create(normalCor)
coroutine.resume(cr) -- this lets you do two while loops at the same time.

function aggroCor() -- when a player is nearby
    while true do
        wait(0.1)
        plrs = game.Players:GetChildren()
        for i,plr in ipairs(plrs) do
            if plr.Character ~= nil then
            tor = plr.Character.Torso
                if (torso.Position-tor.Position).magnitude <= 5 then
                        GoTo = 0
                        Hum:MoveTo(tor.Position)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
cr = coroutine.create(aggroCor)
coroutine.resume(cr)
```

Roblox has the syntax `spawn(aggroCor)` that you can play around with too,
if `coroutine.whatever` seems like too much work.